# I have a problem with performanceSummary chart in performanceAnalytics package in R

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to get the cumulative return for each etf in the chart in the first window it does not work, see below code.

```
library(quantmod)
library(performanceAnalytics)

    enter code here
    library(PerformanceAnalytics)
     startDate = as.Date("2018-01-01") #Specify period of time we are interested in
     endDate = as.Date("2020-01-27") 
      symbols <- c("STW.AX","SPY","VGS.AX","TLT","QQQ","FXI","IWM","SLV","SMH"))  
     getSymbols(symbols)
     #rstw<-(dailyReturn(na.omit(STW.AX)))Australian shares have missing data so make vector row 
    unneven
    #rvgs<- (dailyReturn(na.omit(VGS.AX)))    
     rspy<-(dailyReturn(SPY))
   rtlt<-(dailyReturn(TLT))  
    rslv<-(dailyReturn(SLV))  
    rsmh<- (dailyReturn(SMH))  
       stockr <- c(rspy,rtlt,rslv,rsmh)  
      pf<- data.frame(rspy,rtlt,rqqq,rfxi,riwm,rslv,rsmh)    
    charts.PerformanceSummary(stockr,main='Stock Performance',legend.loc="bottomright")


charts.PerformanceSummary(stockr[,1:4],main='Stock Performance',legend.loc="bottomright")
```

[image]

Comment: I will close this as no one has answered , however from my research thus far , it appears my data has zero values, and or, I am using the wrong chart command I think I should be using charts.rollingPerformance()

Comment: Got it to work the problem lied in the data i was using, I did not need rolling performance chart summary was the right right chart, I needed to cbind the the data as a matrix of xts objects.